# How to make Google sign-in token valid for longer than 1 hour?

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-oauth, access-token, google-signin

I have implemented google sign-in successfully.

I am able to authenticate user and in response I receive token. However the token expires in 1 hour.

`expires_in: "3600"`

I tried searching in the docs - https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference - but cannot find a paramenter to extend the lifespan of the token.

[image]

---

### What I'm actually trying to do?

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

> after a user successfully signs in, send the user's ID token to your server using HTTPS

I'm sending token with each request to the server:

`endpoint/get?access_token=" + access_token`

And then on the server I'm calling `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo`

So I have a token, every request is authenticated, but after 1 hour of working the `tokeninfo` method returns **false** and I need to re-authenticate the user.

In my code I circumvented that by storing all the historical `access_tokens` and if client uses old token I check against historical data and manually issue new token using `refresh_token` *(one of my permissions is to grant offline access)*

---

So yes, I'd be very interested to know:

- How to expand lifespan of the `access_token`?

OR

- Given the limited lifespan how to ensure requests are authenticated on the backend?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As @DaImTo noted, you can't extend the life of an access_token. You can get a new one using a refresh_token, but often if you're trying to do this client side and have a server, you should re-think your approach.

It sounds like there are two "authentications" that you're doing here - the client authenticating against the server, and the server authenticating against the Google service. Right now, the server should be holding onto the refresh token - so it can always re-authenticate against Google. It sounds like you're wrestling with how to authenticate your client against the server after the auth_token timeout.

In general, the client shouldn't send the access_token to the server, nor the refresh_token. What it does is during the first sign-in, the client gets a one-time code (from Google) which it hands to the server. The server uses this to talk to Google and get the access_token and refresh_token, confirming the user has authenticated themselves, and then sends something (usually a cookie) back to the client saying "ok, I've authenticated you. Here is how you keep authenticating yourself for the rest of our conversation."

That later action is pretty standard and is unrelated to oauth itself. The client and server then communicate as they always do - no oauth stuff is exchanged at all, you're relying on the cookie (or equivalent) to keep up the client-server authentication. The server continues to use the auth token and refresh token to talk to Google.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow I think is the best guide to this at the moment. Or at least it is the best one I can find at the moment. It has a good diagram, at least.

The key point is that you're exchanging the brilliantly named "code" with the server (what I was calling the "one-time code"). Once you have done that, the server authenticates you with Google - and it then has the access/refresh tokens and you communicate with the server without having to pass those.

Comment: Thank you taking time to clarify that for me. *"relying on the cookie"* - I was missing that essential part (in the current version was relying on ```access_tokens```)

Comment: I'm confused: cookies are delivered after the user logs on or some more steps must be performed?

Comment: The server would deliver a cookie after it gets the "code" from the client and verifies the code with Google's servers. The cookie is outside OAuth itself and is for convenience in the client-server communication.

Comment: What if I don't want to rely on cookies? I would like to use "bearer token" scheme. A lot of times having the server be entirely stateless (not relying on sessions) is desirable, especially when using serverless. Another disadvantage to using cookies is that your site breaks entirely if the user has "secure browsing" enabled in their browser which disables cookies.

Comment: Assuming Google makes this not easily feasible (short token lifespans) because they don't want you to use them as a JWT server, just a simple one-time identity verification platform.

Answer (score 5):

Access tokens are short lived and only last for one hour this is not something you can extend.

What you need to do is take the refresh token and get a new access token.

**example:**

You take the refresh_token that you got from your initial request and HTTP Post it to: Note: **grant_type=refresh_token**

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
>   client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=1/ffYmfI0sjR54Ft9oupubLzrJhD1hZS5tWQcyAvNECCA&grant_type=refresh_token

**response**

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_XK16As2ZHlScqOxGtntIlevNcasMSPwGiE3pe5ANZfrmJTcsI3ZtAjv4sDrPDRnQ",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600
}
```

Comment: *"I check against historical data and manually issue new token using ```refresh_token```"* - it seems like this is something I'm using already - I'm not sure if this is the right way as: 1) it requires me to store obsolete tokens 2) anyone with historical token gets automatically refreshed to a new one... OK - at least now I know that token is short lived and cannot be extended so I should ask a better question - how the server side know when to ```refresh_token```?

Comment: It requires you to store the "refresh token" which is not obsolete as it will work for as long as the user doesn't revoke your access.   There is no reason to store the access token just get a new one when ever you need it.   You just need to remember to refresh the access token before it expires.    The server side probably doesn't know when it needs to refresh it that's up to you the developer to add to your code that its time to refresh it.  What language are you working with here?

Comment: I store ```refresh_token```. I use ```node.js``` and ```Firebase``` and here is my code authentication code: https://gist.github.com/stefek99/bafee8492128c63aa572 ••• *"There is no reason to store the ```access_token```"* - Why do I store ```access_token```? Let's assume server receives a request and ```access_token``` is invalid (TTL expired). At this point I don't know what to do. By checking if the ```access_token``` was previously valid I can refresh it... There must be a better way, that is why I asked this question in the first place :)

Comment: "Let's assume server receives a request and access_token is invalid (TTL expired). At this point I don't know what to do."   Use the refresh token to request a new access token?   wish we could chat I think you are making this harder then it needs to be.

Comment: Wish we could chat :) I'm at work anyway and my laptop is at home... I'll run some experiments (later on)... My problem in one image: http://i.imgur.com/HRAOh9D.png ••• I know I can use ```refresh_token``` to request ```access_token``` - but what about security? Anyone can fiddle with request to server and potentially obtain token that don't belong to them... ```tokeninfo``` - when expired just returns "expired" and the server shouldn't trust any input coming from client, I'm not willing to return new ```access_token``` to anyone :)

Comment: That's why you shouldn't use a refresh token with client side applications. Normally its used for server sided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91168/discussion-between-daimto-and-michal-stefanow).