# Which google Oauth options to use to for express API and react App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, oauth, google-oauth

I have been in circles on this for hours and read dozens of blogs, articles, how-tos, SO questions, and documentation.

**What I am trying to do:**

- I have a react application that talks to a node/express API.
- I would like to authenticate requests to certain routes using only
  Google OAuth.
- I would also like to persist login for 30 days (at
  least as far as the user knows -- obviously could be refreshing along
  the way)
- I am not using any google services beyond identity information.  Scopes are `email` and `profile`.
- I would like to record which users log in in the mongodb instance

**Here is what's working**:

**Step 1**: Refer user to google from application for authorization

**step 2**: Google refers back to application with authorization

**Step 3**: Application sends **id_token** to backend API

**Step 4**: API asks google to verify **id_token** and it does, returning the data successfully

All of this is outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) by google and works fine up until this point.  I have enough info at this point to throw together some middleware to authenticate routes.

---

This is the point where confusion sets in.  The **id_token** expires after 60 minutes and there is no refresh token in the response.  OK, so I do some reading and I find explanations like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902734/how-to-make-google-sign-in-token-valid-for-longer-than-1-hour).

This says I should be requesting offline access instead, getting a **code**, sending the code to backend and letting the backend talk to google to get both the **id_token** and the **refresh_token** as outlined by Google [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#exchange-authorization-code).

<s>OK, I do that and I get this every time:</s>

```
{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "
}
```

Aside from this error messaging being terribly unhelpful, I compare my request with the google's [Oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) flow and my request looks like their request, but with my config replacing theirs. Note:  I am using postman to try this.

**Questions:**

- For this use case, which of these patterns make the most sense?
- Assuming Code, do I then store the code in a cookie and send with every request?
- There is a mongoDB in use by the API - If I use the code approach Do I just need to store the code and the refresh token to keep this valid for 30 days?
- Can I do any of this without violating REST principles?
- <s>How to resolve the `invalid grant_type:` error?</s>

**EDIT**
I resolved the grant_type error so I have modified the text above accordingly.